# Beautify the tooltips in a Win32 application

Tags: c++, winapi, tooltip

We have a Win32 application which displays tooltips on toolbars etc. The tooltips are very basic rectangles with incorporated text. We would like to be able to beautify these, by for example, having rounded corners, or a gradient filled background. I was unable to find anything which controlled the display settings within the Win32 API set. Does anyone know if this is possible to do, or if there are any third party libraries which create nicer looking toolbars, that can be used within a C++ Win32 application?

Comment: You might want to see the last part of http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/05/07/10301625.aspx

Answer (score 6):

You would have to subclass the [tooltip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760250(v=vs.85).aspx) window (get it by sending a [TB_GETTOOLTIPS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787354(v=vs.85).aspx) message) to override the handlers for WM_PAINT and friends.

Be aware that the user may have customized their theme, fonts, contrast, etc., in order to accommodate visual difficulties.  By overriding how they are drawn, you may make it harder for your user to read them.  Also note that they may no longer blend well with the rest of the theme.

> "Always honor the system color settings, that is, the colors that the user chose in the control panel.  Users have deliberately chosen those colors to give their computer the color scheme they like.  Also, many of your vision-impaired users have deliberately set up schemes that they can see more clearly.  (For that matter, always honor they system fonts so that your text is readable by people who prefer larger fonts.)"  --Joel Spolsky

At a minimum, allow the default appearance if the user has the display in high contrast mode, which you can detect by calling [SystemParametersInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx).